# Выдача прав в зависимости от ресурса в Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

при решении на взгляд не сложной задачи по выдачи прав, формулировка который звучит так:
"Менеджер имеет права на чтение заказа только если он назначен на данный заказ".

Эту проблему я попытался решить с помощью своего сервиса разрешений `PermissionService` где определены методы проверки с подобной сигнатурой:

```
bool CanGetOrder(string userName, int orderId)
```

В данном методе на основе бизнес-правил я проверяю является ли пользователь `userName` менеджером, и назначен ли она на заказ.

Так же на странице msdn нашел данную [статью](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-7.0) которая описывает авторизацию на основе ресурсов. Я попытался использовать данный материал в решении задачи, но меня беспокоит что бизнес-правила, те самые проверки будут зависеть от фреймворка.

Бизнес-правил по выдаче прав может много, ролей в системе уже несколько, и каждое действие почти зависит от этих прав.

Например
"Менеджер может редактировать значения позиций заказа только если он назначен на заказ, и заказ в статусе `Не оформлен`"

Входе разработки эти правило будут изощряться и усложняться, и хотелось бы решить проблему, что бы в будущем было легче ее сопровождать.

В данных примерах я привел аналогии существующим.

Во время написание вопроса возникла идея совместить два способа, таким образом инвертировать зависимость.

Так же узнал про [ABAC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), которая может решить данные задачи, но я не смог найти его реализацию на asp.net core

Как данная задача решается в сложных системах?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону Duende Identity Server, он работает как отдельный сервис для авторизации пользователей, а так же управляет аутентификацией запросов к отдельным ресурсам, вынесенным в API.  Клиентами сервиса могут быть любые приложения (desktop, mobile, API) из любых платформ. Вот в этом [видео](https://youtu.be/nF7lM6V1yOE), немного инфы на русском языке об этом.

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak, Спасибо за информацию. К сожалению текущая архитектура приложения не позволит легко перейти на IdentityServer. Но думаю надо двигаться в его направлении...